# Is $\{(x,\frac1x), x>0\}$ is a connected set

Tags: general-topology

How to see if the set $B=\{(x,\frac1x), x>0\}$ is connected on $(\mathbb{R},|.|)$

Thank you

Comment: You can see it by drawing the graph of $y = 1/x$ for $x>0$. As for proving it: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2018848/proof-that-a-continuous-function-maps-connected-sets-into-connected-sets?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2):

$B=H(0,+\infty)$, where $H$ is the continuous function $$H:(0,+\infty) \to (0,+\infty) \times (0,+\infty), \ H(x)=\left(x,\frac1x\right)$$ and $(0,+\infty)$ is connected. Recall that the image of a connected set by a continuous function is connected.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Pick $(a,b), (c,d) \in B$ and consider $\varphi \colon [0,1] \to A$ 
$$
\varphi(t)= \left(a+(c-a)t, \; \frac{1}{a+(c-a)t}\right).$$
Now *argue* that $\varphi$ is continuous.