# Where does surjectivity fail in a mapping from the unit interval to the Cantor Set?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, connectedness, cantor-set

I'm asked to state why there cannot be a surjective and continuous function $$g: [0,1]\longrightarrow
\text{Cantor Set} $$
I know that $g^{-1}$ exists and is continuous & surjective since the previous exercise was for me to show exactly that.
Now I know that if $g$ were a bijection, then if $g$ were to be continuous, then it would be a homeomorphism and would have to preserve connectedness of $[0,1]$, which it doesn't, implying that $g$ cannot be continuous.

But this requires me to have a bijectivity of $g^{-1}$, where does surjectivity alone enter in this case?

Comment: Hint: connectedness (or its failure)

Comment: The continuous image of a connected space is connected. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2018848/proof-that-a-continuous-function-maps-connected-sets-into-connected-sets). More simply: otherwise, IVT would be violated.

Comment: OH I see, I don't need a homeomorphism for the image of a connected space to be connected, I only need continuity. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $g: [0,1] \to C$ is continuous then $g[[0,1]]$ is connected. The only connected non-empty subsets of $C$ are of the form $\{c\}$ ($C$ is totally disconnected), so $g$ is constant.

Comment: and so it isn't surjective because it is defined as a map $[0,1]\longrightarrow C$ but there are elements of $C$ that are not images of a set in $[0,1]$ by $g$ $\Leftrightarrow$ non-surjectivity.
Thank you! This was very clear.

Comment: @TakenSpark $C$ is uncountable and you only have one point in the image. It doesn't get less surjective than that.